# Rotate and Transform is not working when apply one by one in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am rotating the a panel (Grid) and Flip (Transform) the panel. When i do this separate, both are working fine. Rotate and then Flip (OR) Flip and Rotate is not working fine.

I am rotating the panel to 90 degree every time. When i rotate to 90 degree, the panel height and width is changed. In that case, if i Flip the panel, issue occur. For 180 degree, no issue.

**Issue Steps**
**Step-1:** Rotate image to 90 degree by clicking the rotate button in the sample. You will get the below output.

[image]

**Step-2:** Now Flip the image by Transform button and the image moved to left side. Expected output is, It should be center and Flip.

[image]

You can see the difference of Transformation of image, by directly clicking Transform button, without click on Rotate.

This is my code.

**[XAML]:**

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/Buldingimage.jpeg"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="0">Rotate</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_2" Grid.Column="1">Transform</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**[C#]:**

```
    double rotationAngle = 0;
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Rotate
        this.rotationAngle += 90;
        this.grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        this.grid1.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = this.rotationAngle };
    }

    bool mIsHorizontalImageflipped = false;
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Transform
        int[] value ;
        float[] origin = new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f };
        string path = "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)";
        if (!this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped)
        {
            value = new int[] { 1, -1 };
            this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped = false;
          value = new int[] { -1, 1 };
        }
        this.Animate(value, origin, path);
    }
    internal void Animate(int[] value, float[] origin, string path)
    {
        this.grid1.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        this.grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(origin[0], origin[1]);
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames keyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        SplineDoubleKeyFrame keyFrame = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        keyFrame.Value = value[0];
        keyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
        keyFrame = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        KeySpline keySpline = new KeySpline();
        keySpline.ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.64, 0.84);
        keySpline.ControlPoint2 = new Point(0, 1);

        keyFrame.KeySpline = keySpline;
        keyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
        keyFrame.Value = value[1];
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(keyFrames, new PropertyPath(path));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(keyFrames, this.grid1);
        sb.Children.Add(keyFrames);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

[Click here](https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/WpfApp1.zip) to download the sample.

Please provide suggestion or what i did wrong on this.

Regards,

Bharathi.

Comment: *"is not working fine ... issue occur"* - what kind of issue?

Comment: After rotate 90 degree, then Flip, Image position is move wrongly . Not in center

Comment: Note that RenderTransformOrigin (as the name implies) has no effect on the LayoutTransform. If you need to apply multiple Transforms at the same time, use a TransformGroup or a MatrixTransform for the RenderTransform.

Comment: @Clemens Can you look my sample from the above link and provide better some better solution?

Comment: Perhaps with a detailed explanation of what exactly you are trying to achieve. Right now it's not clear to me.

Comment: I have updated my Posts. Please check it now. I hope it will clear now

Comment: @Bharathi: Did you try my suggestion? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @mm8 Yes. Checked. after rotate, I i clicked Transform, image centered. But it is not maintained rotation Angle.

Comment: @Bharathi: So you need a `TransformGroup` to be able to apply several different transforms at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `RenderTransform` property to a `ScaleTransform`, you are effectively removing the `RotateTransform` and vice versa.

To be able to apply both transforms simultaneously, you could use a `TransformGroup`:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/Buldingimage.jpeg"/>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rt" />
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

You would then simply change the `Angle` of the `RotateTransform` and animate the `ScaleTransform` as before:

```
double rotationAngle = 0;
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Rotate
    this.rotationAngle += 90;
    this.grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    rt.Angle = this.rotationAngle;
}

bool mIsHorizontalImageflipped = false;
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Transform
    int[] value;
    float[] origin = new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f };
    string path = "RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX";
    if (!this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped)
    {
        value = new int[] { 1, -1 };
        this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.mIsHorizontalImageflipped = false;
        value = new int[] { -1, 1 };
    }
    this.Animate(value, origin, path);
}

internal void Animate(int[] value, float[] origin, string path)
{
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    this.grid1.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(origin[0], origin[1]);
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames keyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    SplineDoubleKeyFrame keyFrame = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
    keyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    keyFrame.Value = value[0];
    keyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
    keyFrame = new SplineDoubleKeyFrame();
    keyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    KeySpline keySpline = new KeySpline();
    keySpline.ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.64, 0.84);
    keySpline.ControlPoint2 = new Point(0, 1);

    keyFrame.KeySpline = keySpline;
    keyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
    keyFrame.Value = value[1];
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(keyFrames, new PropertyPath(path));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(keyFrames, this.grid1);
    sb.Children.Add(keyFrames);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. I will check and confirm soon.. i am in vacation now.